# Multiple App version according to Android version

Tags: android, google-play, version

Did you know where we can find the version max of an app according to android version.

For example:

-user with a android 4.4.2 device could download the version 2 of my app

-user with a android 6.0 device could download the version 3 of my app

Where can i find this list?

Thanks for your advice

Arnaud

Comment: Seems better way is check `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` in your App when it needed and make the implementation of each version.

Comment: thanks, but i want to check if user has the most recent update available for  his phone, so i check the customer version of my app, the customer version of android and i want to get bakc the most recent version available for this customer.

Comment: I understand. But it would be difficult to support a number of projects: for sure some logic will be changed in different project.

Answer (score 1):

Try use [Multi APK Support](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) with appropriate API level. More details You can find in [Official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html) and, for example, [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/10/11/use-the-multiple-apk-support-in-android-market/)